# how to call js function in lightgallery onCloseAfter.lg method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, lightgallery

i m using the `lightgallery` jquery plugin from https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/

so the `lightgallery` is working properly. In `lightgallery` there is a method `onCloseAfter` which means `Executes immediately once lightgallery is closed`

Here is the code

```
var $lg = $('.lightgallery');
        $lg.on("onCloseAfter.lg", function() {
         alert('onCloseAfter : Executes immediately once Colorbox is closed;');
         Test();
         
                        });
```

simple `js` function

```
function Test(){
 alert("hello")
}
```

`Test`function trigger once when the `lightgallery` is closed  how to call this `function` everytime when the `lightgallery` is closed?

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have more than one gallery on your page ?

Comment: no only one gallery

Comment: the gallery is on another page but using iframe i m binding its url in iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of [lightGallery](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/docs/api.html#events) this shoud work

```
var $lg = $('#lightgallery');

$lg.lightGallery();

// Fired immediately once lightgallery is closed.
$lg.on('onCloseAfter.lg', function (event) {
    Test();
});
function Test() {
    alert("hello")
}
```